# Inequality for Euclidean norm

Tags: stochastic-processes, normed-spaces, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let:| | be  Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and 
 $b :  \mathbb{R}^{n}\longmapsto \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\sigma :  \mathbb{R}^{n}\longmapsto \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$  two continuous functions.

Suppose there exist a constant $C_{1}$ such that :
$$ |b(x)|+|\sigma(x)| \leq C_{1}(1+|x|) \forall  x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}. $$
How we can show that this implies that , for fixed $p \geq $2, we can find a constant $C_{2} > 0$ such that :
$$
 p |x|^{p-2}x.b(x)+\frac{1}{2}p(p-1)|x|^{p-2}|\sigma(x)|^{2}\leq C_{2}(1+|x|^{p}) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}?
$$

you can find my question here [reference](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~mike/StoCal/lecture20.pdf)

I'll be grateful for any help offered!

Comment: @Educ: the second constant $C$ is not the same as the first constant $C$, right? Perhaps it would be better to write $C_1$ and $C_2$ ?

Comment: @Educ: I see that this inequality is used in the proof of the moment bound. In general, for $1\le p\lt\infty$ you have, for $u\ge0$,
$$
(1+u^p)\le(1+u)^p\le2^{p-1}(1+u^p)
$$
so you can often use $1+u^p$ and $(1+u)^p$ interchangeably by throwing in a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p\ge2$ and $u\ge0$, Jensen's inequality gives
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1+u^2}{2}\right)^{p/2}&\le\frac{1+u^p}{2}\tag{1}\\
\left(1+u^2\right)^{p/2}&\le2^{p/2-1}\left(1+u^p\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{u^{p-2}(1+u^2)}{1+u^p}
&=\left(\frac{u^p}{1+u^p}\right)^{1-2/p}
\left(\frac{(1+u^2)^{p/2}}{1+u^p}\right)^{2/p}\tag{3}\\
&\le1^{1-2/p}\left(2^{p/2-1}\right)^{2/p}\tag{4}\\
&=2^{1-2/p}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: $\frac{u^p}{1+u^p}\le1$ and $(2)$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
&p|x|^{p-2}x\cdot b(x)+\tfrac12p(p-1)|x|^{p-2}|\sigma(x)|^2\tag{6}\\
&=p|x|^{p-2}\left(x\cdot b(x)+\tfrac12(p-1)|\sigma(x)|^2\right)\tag{7}\\
&\le p|x|^{p-2}\left(|x|\,|b(x)|+\tfrac12(p-1)C_1^2(1+|x|)^2\right)\tag{8}\\
&\le p|x|^{p-2}\left(C_1(1+|x|)^2+\tfrac12(p-1)C_1^2(1+|x|)^2\right)\tag{9}\\
&\le p|x|^{p-2}\left(C_1+\tfrac12(p-1)C_1^2\right)(1+|x|)^2\tag{10}\\
&\le p(C_1+\tfrac12(p-1)C_1^2)2^{1-2/p}(1+|x|^p)\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\ \ (7)$: factor out $|x|^{p-2}$
$\ \ (8)$: apply Hölder to $x\cdot b(x)$ and $|\sigma(x)|\le C_1(1+|x|)$
$\ \ (9)$: use $|x|\le1+|x|$ and $|b(x)|\le C_1(1+|x|)$
$(10)$: factor out $(1+|x|)^2$
$(11)$: $(5)$

So set $C_2=p(C_1+\tfrac12(p-1)C_1^2)2^{1-2/p}$

Comment: Thanks but i can't see  how did you to go from line 4 to 5

Comment: @Educ: $|x|^{p-2}\le(1+|x|)^{p-2}$ However, I am going to give a better bound in a minute.

Comment: Thanks but is that true $(1+|x|)^{p}\leq 2^{p-1}(1+|x|^{p})$

Comment: @Educ: yes, by [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). In the improved bounds, I use $(1)$, which is true because $f(x)=x^{p/2}$ is convex for $p\ge2$.